# Microsoft.Bot.Connector: Authorization for Microsoft App ID 'X' failed with status code Forbidden

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a Bot app on Azure using Azure Bot Service. It is a language-understanding Bot. Since I created from Azure, all the configuration (app registration on Microsoft and at LUIS) were done from Azure Portal.

After creating some intents and entities at LUIS, when I try to test my app via Azure Portal, I am getting
`Functions.messages. Microsoft.Bot.Connector: Authorization for Microsoft App ID e1f860e9-eced-4417-9dac-f77eb985ed19 failed with status code Forbidden.`

After some research I found that error is thrown by line

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new BasicLuisDialog());
```

I found some  threads with same issue but none of them helped.

I am using following channels
[image]

and I am testing from Azure portal

[image]

Since Azure Bot Service is still in preview stage, there is no forum at MSDN related to Bot Service.

Any help much appreciated.

update:

In my azure portal I am seeing following error. Its strange becaue I am the admin of my subscription
[image]

Comment: 401 is an authentication failure. Are the Bot App Id and password setup correctly?

Comment: Yes. I have check it many times in appsettings and printing the info into the log.var appId = Utils.GetAppSetting("LuisAppId");
    var appKey = Utils.GetAppSetting("LuisAPIKey");
    log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!{appId}  haha{appKey}"); its logging correct appid and key

Comment: It may be different in Bot Service, but in my bots the settings are `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`

Comment: In azure portal , it is correctly set in app settings .. veen in the error iM getting correct appId

Comment: @stuartd  : I have just updated the question.

Comment: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/manage/debug/ may help

Comment: I think that your problem is requested url. You should have something like : yourbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages as endpoint.

Comment: Make screenshot of your microsoft.bot.framework configuration and paste here.